# Why is SQL Server 2012 faster than MongoDB for this query

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, sql-server-2012

I am doing some performance tests between SQL Server 2012 and MongoDB 2.4.9. I have done a little research online and found many comparisons that compare only insert performance between these two databases. I am only interested in `select`performance without indexes. I setup a very simple test. Here are the specs

**SQL Server setup**

- Setup SQL Server with only one integer field.
- Insert 1 million random integers

**MongoDB setup**

- Has two fields _id and id1
- Insert 1 million random integers into id1 field

When I inserted the numbers they are the exact same numbers going into both databases. The random numbers range from 1 to 1000.

**SQL Server query**

```
select id from a101 where id > 995
```

**MongoDB query**

```
var q = Query.GT("id1", 995);        
foreach (var i in collection.Find(q))
{
     values.Add(i.id1);
}
```

**Results:**

- SQL Server: 192 ms
- MongoDB: 1109 ms

For my schema I will not need any joins and will have only denormalized data - this is why I considered MongoDB. I expected mongoDB to be many times faster than SQL Server after reading the benchmarks online. Is there something I may be doing wrong? Again, I wanted to test without indexes.

Comment: Too many inequalities. Why different schema's?How do you measure the sql server query? Do you read the results of it? What type is values in the mongo db query? Why do you loop through the results? Etc...

Comment: Do you have indexes on tables?

Comment: I measure both queries by using the StopWatch class. There are only integers in MongoDB (_id: object, id1: integer). I loop through both sql server and MongoDB. There is only about  600 results coming from both queries. Do you think the loop will effect it.

Comment: Your question is too broad for StackOverflow ... there are too many variables. RAM, disk, CPU, network, etc. And does the query actually represent something real? I'd store it to disk, and index it in both cases if I was concerned about actual best-case performance. Having done some recent perf comparisons with MongoDB and other options ... it's often not the fastest or best choice. It depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - I would accept your argument but in my tests sql server is 5 times faster than MongoDB. There must be an explanation of why this is. Also, this is on my personal desktop that is not connected to a network.

Comment: It sounds like you expect MongoDB to be faster? Why? Also -- your code for doing queries isn't identical. You should have more similar code. Maybe using Linq and adding to a List as you're doing.

Comment: Well didn't want to spark a heated debate. Just wanted to know if anyone can point me in the right direction of why the performance gap is big.

Comment: And in a simiar test on my machine, MongoDb returned documents in 435ms. When indexed, 125ms.

Comment: Sorry if you think this is heated -- I just think this is too broad as you're trying to compare two very different DB technologies, without explaining much and not using either necessarily as it should be used. The same test on my PC for example takes 2ms when done entirely in memory. :)

Comment: @WiredPrairie - Actually, for this test I choose to not use indexes. We are uploading thousands csv files to the database. Each csv will be uploaded to a separate collection or table. We will not have the resources to index specific fields. Any given csv can be from a few hundred records to a little less than a million. Let me know if you know how to optimize MongoDB without indexes.

Comment: I'd expect the performance will change measurably when you use your actual data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MongoDB is likely five times slower in this case because it needs to read and output five times as much data.

One row in your SQL table is just 4 byte. But in MongoDB it is a 4 byte integer plus a 12 byte ObjectId. Also, the field-names are part of each individual document. The strings `_id` and `id1` are part of each document you retrieve, so some additional bytes are added.

And this is just the actual payload. When you look at [BSONSpec.org](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) you can see that your document is represented by:

- 4 byte for a 32bit integer which is the total length of the document
- 1 byte `0x01` for "now comes an ObjectId"
- 4 bytes for the null-terminated string `_id`
- 12 bytes for the ObjectId
- 1 byte `0x10` for "now comes a 32bit integer" (smallest integer there is)
- 4 bytes for the null-terminated string `id1`
- 4 bytes for the 32bit integer
- 1 trailing `0x00` which marks the end of the document

which is a total of 31 byte.

Comment: Ah..That will make since. I will alter my tests to account for this issue.

Comment: So you will have a minimum of 12 byte per row plus additional fields

Comment: @IvanJuarez plus 4 byte for the total length of the document, 1 byte for the type indicator `0x07` ("this is an objectID"), 4 byte for the key-name `_id` (null-terminated string), then the 12 byte ObjectId, and finally 1 byte for a trailing `0x00` at the end of the document, so a minimal document requires at least 22 byte. For more information: http://bsonspec.org/spec.html